# File b'content/train.csv' does not exist Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

First time using Google Colab. I have used a Kaggle API and I have the data loaded into Google Colab, but I can't seem to open it via pandas. I right clicked on the file and copied path. I then ran the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_csv("content/train.csv") 
test = pd.read_csv('content/test.csv')
```

The error code that I am getting:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'content/train.csv' does not exist
```

Here is the code for everything I have done leading up to this error:

```
!pip install kaggle
from google.colab import files
files.upload() #Uploaded my kaggle.json file

!pip install -q kaggle
!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle
!cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/

!kaggle competitions download -c microsoft-malware-prediction

#Unzip the files:
!7z x train.csv.zip
!7z x sample_submission.csv.zip
!7z x test.csv.zip

#remove the zipped data
!rm train.csv.zip
!rm sample_submission.csv.zip
!rm test.csv.zip

import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_csv("content/train.csv") 
test = pd.read_csv('content/test.csv') 
print('read')
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you missing a leading `/` in your path? i.e., `/content/...` rather than `content/...`.

Comment: Hello. Yes, I have included that. I am now suspecting that it is a permission issue with the source in which I am getting the data. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It happened to me too but I was able to resolve with reading the .csv file with a new syntax:

- Enter this in a code block above (1st or second)

`!pip install -U -q PyDrive`

`from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth`

`from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive`

`from google.colab import auth`
`from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials`

`#Authenticate and create the PyDrive client`

`auth.authenticate_user()`

`gauth = GoogleAuth()`

`gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()`

`drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)`

### Then do this:

`link = 'link_to_file_in drive'`

`fluff, id = link.split('=')`

`downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':id})`

`downloaded.GetContentFile('name_of_file.csv')`

`df = pd.read_csv("name_of_file.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

i encountered with the same issue , what fixed it for me was :

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# PyDrive reference:
# https://gsuitedevs.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/index.html

# 2. Create & upload a file text file.
uploaded = drive.CreateFile({'title': 'Sample upload.txt'})
uploaded.SetContentString('Sample upload file content')
uploaded.Upload()
print('Uploaded file with ID {}'.format(uploaded.get('id')))

# 3. Load a file by ID and print its contents.
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': uploaded.get('id')})

print('Downloaded content "{}"'.format(downloaded.GetContentString()))
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)
    root_dir = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/"
    base_dir = root_dir + 'app/'
    and then each file is refreed as base_dir +file_name
```

from https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=zU5b6dlRwUQk

Answer (score 0):

Provide the full path for the file irrespective of where you are.

Try below solution, hope it works if you are fetching data from google drive

```
data = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/data/"name_of_the_csv_file")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a file in Google Drive:

`df=pd.read_csv(" copy and paste the entire path of that file")`